# Optimize netsuite script

Tags: javascript, performance, netsuite

I have a record with a sublist, and every item of that sublist is a record that has another sublist. What I want is, for every itemA get all the sublist of every itemA sublist. Like this

```
Bill of lading1
  ->FulfillmentA
      ->Item123
      ->Item124
      ->Item125
  ->FulfillmentB
      ->Item224
      ->Item226
      ->Item227
```

I want to be able to create a table like this for every Bill of Lading

```
Fulfillment | Item | Description | Qty
```

For example for 1 Bill of lading that has 2 fulfillments and each of those fulfillments has 3 items

```
               BILL OF LADING #4
Fulfillment | Item | Description | Qty
-------------------------------------------
    A       |  123 |     xxxx    |  2
            |  124 |     xxxx    |  1
            |  125 |     xxxx    |  7
--------------------------------------------
    B       |  224 |     xxxx    |  1
            |  226 |     xxxx    |  1
            |  227 |     xxxx    |  1
```

I can do this, the problem comes when some fullfilment has like 60-70 fulfillments, then I get an Script Execution Usage Limit Exceeded error.

The basic idea with my code is to create an object like this:

```
   * { 
   *   70: {
   *     itemNumber : {
   *        description: xxxx,
   *        quantity: XX
   *     },
   *     itemNumber2 : {
   *        description: xxxx,
   *        quantity: XX
   *     },
   *   71: { ...},
   *   ....
   * }
```

Then with a loop create the table.

The problem I think is with this line:

```
fulfillmentArray.push(nlapiLoadRecord('itemFulfillment', fullfillmentInternalIDArray[z]));
```

Because when I remove it on a BOL that has 100 fullfilments it works

Here is my code:

```
var lines = record.getLineItemCount('recmachcustrecord_id_billoflading');
//Grab the fulfillment internal id
for(var i = 1; i <= lines; i++){
    fullfillmentInternalIDArray.push(record.getLineItemValue('recmachcustrecord_id_billoflading', 'custrecord_fulfillment', i) ); 
}

//Get the fulfillment number
for(var x = 1; x <= lines; x++){
    fulfillmentNumberArray.push(record.getLineItemText('recmachcustrecord_id_billoflading', 'custrecord_fulfillment', x).replace(/Fulfillment|#|Item/g,"")); 
}

//Get the fulfillments and push them into an array
//And create an empty object with the fulfillment number
for(var z = 0; z < fullfillmentInternalIDArray.length; z++){
    fulfillmentArray.push(nlapiLoadRecord('itemFulfillment', fullfillmentInternalIDArray[z]));
    billOfLadingFulfillmentsObject[ fulfillmentNumberArray[z] ] = {};
}
```

Then create the rest of the object:

```
for(var j = 0; j < fulfillmentArray.length; j++){
  itemCount = fulfillmentArray[j].getLineItemCount('item');

  for(var y = 1; y <= itemCount; y++){
      billOfLadingFulfillmentsObject[ fulfillmentNumberArray[j] ][ fulfillmentArray[j].getLineItemValue('item', 'itemname', y) ] = {};
  }  

  for(var item in billOfLadingFulfillmentsObject){
      for(var item2 in billOfLadingFulfillmentsObject[item]){
          for(var y = 1; y <= itemCount; y++){
              if(item2 === fulfillmentArray[j].getLineItemValue('item', 'itemname', y)){
                    billOfLadingFulfillmentsObject[ fulfillmentNumberArray[j] ][item2]['description'] = fulfillmentArray[j].getLineItemValue('item', 'itemdescription', y);
                    billOfLadingFulfillmentsObject[ fulfillmentNumberArray[j] ][item2]['quantity'] = fulfillmentArray[j].getLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', y);
              }
          } 
      }
  }
}
```

I dont know how to optimize so when there are lots of fulfillments it doesn't throw an Script Execution Usage Limit Exceeded error.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing a search to retrieve that bulk of the data because it's cheaper.  Loop through the items collecting item ids and do a search to get the data.